# php class return; function return

Tags: php

object var $c->$var1 has been changed in class a;

var $new_var has not be changed in function d;
i was a litte puzzled.
my english is poor,can you understand me?

```
<?php
    class a{
        public function test () {
            $b = new b;
            $c = new c;
            $b->test($c);
            var_dump($c);
        } 
    }

    class b{
        public function test($c) {
            $c->var1 = 2;
            return $c;
        }
    }

    class c {
        public $var1 = 1;
    }

    $a = new a;
    $a->test();

    function d($new_var) {
        $new_var = 2;
        return $new_var;
    }

    $new_var = 1;
    d($new_var);
    echo $new_var
```

Comment: The function `d()` is setting the var `$new_var` to the value `2` no matter what you pass to that function, can you be more clear what is your question anyway cuz i'm not sure i got your query

Comment: but $c has been changed in  this line  $b->test($c);

Comment: Still can't get where is the problem here!

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you have this function

```
function d($new_var) {
        $new_var = 2;
        return $new_var;
}
```

Where is it true that you maybe pass a different variable as parameter, but then you take that parameter and you decide to set it = 2 and then return it. 
If you want to return what you passed you should change it in

```
function d($new_var) {
        return $new_var;
}
```

Or if you want something similar to test function of class b try tgus

```
function d($new_var) {
    $d->new_var = $new_var;
    return $d;
}
```

So you can access to your $new_var in the returned objecd $d

Answer (score 0):

You expect the following piece of code to change the value for `$new_var` from `1` to `2`, right?

```
$new_var = 1;
d($new_var);
echo $new_var
```

Alas, that cannot be, because the returned value is never assigned back to the variable. To make sure the passed variable will retain its new value even outside the scope of the function it was passed to as an argument, you need to pass the variable as a reference instead of as a value, like this:

```
function d(&$new_var) {
    $new_var = 2;
    return $new_var;
}
```

Notice the ampersand (`&`) in front of the variable name in the signature of the function. This will cause the variable to be [passed as a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), so that it will retain any changes made to it inside the function.